# Converting form input into a clickable url in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this form field:

```
<%= f.url_field :url, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Website" %>
```

I'd like to be able to have the user impute a URL and then have it automatically post as a clickable link. Right now all it does is submit a string that you'd have to copy and past.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  You have a form, and URL field.  The user enters a website into the URL field.  Then what happens?  Should the form be posted to your controller at this point?  Should the page change after the form has posted rendering the link?  "Automatically post as a clickable link" is throwing me off :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The user inputs a link into a form, this link then renders on the index as <%= startup.url %> but that is just a string. How can I make it so that it's a blue link and the user clicks on it will go to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment:  Change the index view to render a link instead of rendering plain text like so.

```
<%= link_to startup.url, startup.url %>
```

Or, if you're not forcing them to enter http:// in the form you can do

```
<%= link_to startup.url, "http://#{startup.url}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks that was it! I appreciate the help! just needed the right syntax:)